# Failing to read value XML attribute in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to read a file produced by another developer.  The file looks something like this.  I am trying to read in the value for 'ProfileName', but when I look at the object in memory, I see null for the Value (capital V) attribute.  The only place I can see the string "GolfLeague-Dual" is in the outerxml attribute, but I would have to parse through a bunch of just to get it.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TopNode>
  <ProfileSettings>
    <ProfileName value="GolfLeague-Dual" />    
  </ProfileSettings>
</TopNode>
```

Here is my code to try to read this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(directory + @"\Settings.xml");

XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("//ProfileSettings");

foreach (XmlNode node in nodes) {
    Console.WriteLine(node["ProfileName"].Value);
}
```

Comment: I highly recommend that you consider switching to the Linq-to-XML dom instead.  It's much improved over the old one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is trying to get the inner value of the node, not an attribute called `value`.  Try this instead...

```
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes) {
    Console.WriteLine(node["ProfileName"].Attributes["value"].Value);
}
```

Here's a working dotnetfiddle...

**https://dotnetfiddle.net/pmJKbX**